# Splitting a string into a pattern of commands

Tags: regex, string

I need to take a string of concatenated keyword commands and numbers, and put the commands and the numbers into lists.

**Pattern:**

{command words} by {number} {command words} by {number} etc...

**Input string:**

```
 "turn right by 1 turn left by 99 up by 11 left by 28"
```

I thought I might split on the word " by " but that causes the second group to have the number and the next command (eg. 1 turn left).

**Regex:**

```
 \sby\s
```

**Desired Output:**

```
 turn right by 1 
 turn left by 99 
 up by 11 
 left by 28
```

**Desired Lists:**

```
 turn right,turn left,up,left
 1,99,11,28
```

How can I split a long string of commands that follow that pattern?

The text is one big long string with no punctuation. The word by is always followed by a number and the pattern is consistent. The first part may contain one or two keyword commands.

Comment: What tools are you using to run your regex?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/HvWctq/1

Comment: `([^\d]+)\s+(\d+)(?:\s+|$)` : from this group1 of the matches will make your command list. group2 of the matches can make your number list.

Comment: `([\w ]+?)(?=\s*by\s*)\D+(\d+)\s*`?

Comment: @bulbus you could simplify `[^\d]` with `\D`

Comment: You could also use this: `(\w[\w ]+?)(?=\s*by\s*)\D+\K\d+`. It produces one less capture group

Comment: @ctwheels it will drop everything before so you would lose the command?

Comment: @ctwheels my bad it would still capture the group but not in the full match! neat

Comment: Simplest form I could come up with is `(\w[\w ]*?)\s*by\s*(\d+)`

Comment: If the command is always "turn right/left" or "up" and the preposition is always "by", Wiktor's solution is the best choice. OP will need to clarify, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

It seems your strings all share the same structure: `word or words by 111` (one or more words, followed by `by` literally, followed by at least one digit)

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/XvohpV/2)

```
(\w[\w ]*?)\s+by\s+(\d+)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
turn right by 1 turn left by 99 up by 11 left by 28
```

#### Output

1. Full Match: `turn right by 1`

   - Group 1: `turn right`
   - Group 2: `1`
2. Full Match: `turn left by 99`

   - Group 1: `turn left`
   - Group 2: `99`
3. Full Match: `up by 11`

   - Group 1: `up`
   - Group 2: `11`
4. Full Match: `left by 28`

   - Group 1: `left`
   - Group 2: `28`

---

### Explanation

- `(\w[\w ]*?)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `\w[\w ]*?` Any word character, followed by anything in the set `[\w ]` (any word character or space) any number of times, but as few as possible
- `\s+by\s+` One or more spaces followed by `by` literally, followed by one or more spaces.
- `(\d+)` Capture one or more digits into capture group 2